# ASP.NET web forms - how to combine WIF authentification with membership provider and role provider

Tags: asp.net, wif, membership-provider, roleprovider

I'm using windows identity foundation with form authentification in ASP.NET Web Forms in .NET 4.5
How can I combine WIF form authentification with my custom membership provider and my custom role provider defined in web.config?

I want to use my custom membership provider for load additional user info from SQL DB such as email, birthday, avatar iamge.
I want to use my custom role provider to obtain all roles from SQL DB for authentificated user.

My authentification method Authenticate(userName, password) is called from Login.aspx LoginButtonClick:

```
    public static ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string userName, string password)
    {
        var principal = AuthenticateWindowsUser(userName, password);
        var inputIdentity = (WindowsIdentity)principal.Identity;

        var outputIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(inputIdentity.AuthenticationType);
        outputIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, inputIdentity.Name));
        return new ClaimsPrincipal(outputIdentity);
    }

    private static WindowsPrincipal AuthenticateWindowsUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            SecurityToken securityToken = new UserNameSecurityToken(userName, password);
            var handlers = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;

            //Uses default WindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler
            return new WindowsPrincipal((WindowsIdentity)handlers.ValidateToken(securityToken)[0]);
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenValidationException ex)
        {
            ShowException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the provided code works for you it should be

```
public static ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string userName, string password)
{
    var principal = AuthenticateWindowsUser(userName, password);
    var inputIdentity = (WindowsIdentity)principal.Identity;

    var outputIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(inputIdentity.AuthenticationType);
    outputIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, inputIdentity.Name));

    // other information from the membership provider
    var user = Membership.GetUser( userName ) );
    outputIdentity.AddClaim( new Claim( ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email ) );
    ...

    // roles from role provider
    foreach ( string role in Roles.GetRolesForUser( userName ) )
       outputIdentity.AddClaim( new Claim( ClaimTypes.Role, role ) );

    return new ClaimsPrincipal(outputIdentity);
}
```

Comment: @paul: why would you try this code to pass through your adfs claims? Seems you try to apply an answer to wrong question to your scenario. Also, seems you need to create your own question.

Comment: @Wiktor, Sorry, new to ADFS and Claims ..I used above code to authenticate my users, but would also like to retrieve the LDAP attributes passed as claims as setup on the AD FS server's Relying Part Trust. I've created a new question for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084449/asp-net-wif-retrieve-ldap-attributes-as-claims-from-ad-fs-server  I deleted my previous comment since it was not correct to post it here.